# Reordering item in PBS queue

Tags: pbs

Iv'e submitted several jobs to PBS. Now, I want the job I submitted that last will be the first.

One option is to hold all the previews jobs (using qhold ). The problem is that I used `-W depend=afterok:` switch in order to enable jobs just after previews job ended.

Therefore, my PBS queue look something like that:

```
468743.server   username    queue_name job1         4828   6  36   46gb 24:00 R 16:12
468744.server   username    queue_name job1_cont     --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468745.server   username    queue_name job1_cont     --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468746.server   username    queue_name job1_cont     --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468747.server   username    queue_name job1_cont     --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468748.server   username    queue_name job1_cont     --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468743.server   username    queue_name job2         4828   6  36   46gb 24:00 R 16:12
468744.server   username    queue_name job2_cont     --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468745.server   username    queue_name job2_cont     --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468746.server   username    queue_name job2_cont     --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468747.server   username    queue_name job2_cont     --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468748.server   username    queue_name job2_cont     --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468753.server   username    queue_name NewJob        --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468754.server   username    queue_name NewJob_cont        --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   -- 
468755.server   username    queue_name NewJob_cont        --    6  36   46gb 24:00 H   --
```

Now, I want **NewJob**, which is last on line, to run after the first job in {job1, job2} is finished, and before any of the "_cont". And I want the NewJob_cont jobs will run after NewJob.

Can I alter the position of **NewJob** in line without destroying the rest of the hold-queue hierarchy?

Comment: What scheduler are you using to run these jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use qalter to change dependencies for jobs. You can execute:

```
qalter 468744 -W depend=after:468753
qalter 468753 -W depend=after:468743
```

This will make it so that 468744 doesn't execute until after the new job and the new job doesn't execute until after the first job. Just as you can add after dependencies to queued jobs, you can also add other kinds of dependencies.

Comment: That's an option, but as I have 10 more "job#" other then 1 and two, and I'll have to postponed all of them to after my NewJob, it will be rather annoying. 

Further more, while NewJob is running, other jobs can run also, upto  the limit set by the server administrator. 

So this solution is not ideal. 

Thanks anyway,
Ronen.

Comment: You can use the afterstart dependency if you want them to run after that job.

Comment: yes, but if I want to move more then one job up, it will be very complicated. I want to reorder linear queue, not to reshuffle complicated dependency graph.

Comment: What scheduler are you using?